# Import path using same file from differet location

Tags: python

I have this structure:

```
Folder1
 - program.py
Folder2
 - module1.py
 - module2.py
 - test.py
```

In `module2.py` i have
`from module1 import *`
In `program.py` I have from `from Folder2.module2 import *`
But `program.py` cannot find `module1`

How to properly load nested modules?

Comment: you can add __init__.py file in Folder1 and Folder2 and then you can import and find that

Answer (score 1):

You can add the path to `Folder2` into your `syspath` and import the desired modules.

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/Folder2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you recheck your commands

```py
from Folder1 import *
from Folder2.module1 import *
from Folder2.module2 import *
```

Comment: Thanks. But this I want to avoid. If I'm already loading module1 into module2, I do not want to load module1 again in program.py.